Using a method of a generic class template in a specialized template class
let's suppose we have a file called a.cpp and a file called a.h, we have defined in the file a.h the class Example
//File a.h
template< typename V, typename C >
class Example{
public:   

void foo(void){
//use of a variable declared in private fields of a.h and of a.cpp
gmp = new C;
tmp = new V;
tmp->something(...);
}


private:
V tmp;
C gmp;
}

and we define specialized class Example in file.cpp
//File a.cpp
template< typename C >
class Example<int, C>{
 
//We won't to define foo here because we want to use the generic method
//We define fun() that use gmp variable declared in generic Example class 
void fun(void){
print(gmp);
print(tmp);
}

private:
int tmp;

}

I'm wondering, which tmp variable is used in generic Class function foo().
Can gmp variable be used in the function fun() of the specialized class?
This is a sample of my issue, i'm expecting to use gmp variable in fun() function and if i can use V tmp in fun() function in the .cpp file

It's simple: Example<int, C> will have no foo() and will have no gmp -  Example<int, C> is a completely different and unrelated type. Partial specialization doesn't work the way you think it does.

@Evg So, for use gmp and have foo() i have to extend the generic class? is it possible for a partial specialization to extend the generic class whom which it's specialized?

You can define ExampleBase<V, C> and then derive Example<int, C> from ExampleBase<int, C>.

In my specific case my ExampleBase<V, C> extends the same class that Example<V,C> extends, supposing the class was public A.
I solved using ExampleBase<V,C>: virtual public A,
Example<V, C>: virtual public A, public ExampleBase<V, C> otherwise i get ambiguos conversion
